# how to create a salesforce object on a marketing cloud smart capture form submission

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, landing-page, create-records, smart-capture

I have a landing page with a smart capture form on it. Upon the form submission, the smart capture simply sends the details into specific data Extention. Now, is it possible to create a 'Lead' object as well once the form is submitted?
I have been trying to use the CreateSalesforceObject function here but it seems not working with the smart capture form as the self-generated Html code is not supported in the function.
Can someone please guide how to achieve this requirement?
I would be extremely thankful.

Comment: This looks very much as a copy of [your question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321194/creating-a-salesforce-lead-on-smart-capture-submission) from few weeks ago. Please refrain from asking same, or very similar, questions multiple times. Once you gain sufficient reputation, you will be able to put bounty on it to attract attention. However for now, patience is the only way.

Comment: @LukasLunow extremely apologize for this act but I am totally stuck at this point. please try to understand the problem and if you know any solution. I would be thankful to take that.

Comment: Are you comfortable doing a custom solution with Ampscript? If yes - this is a way to do it: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/09/22/create-a-sales-service-cloud-integrated-lead-capture-form-using-ampscript/

Comment: Hi @MikeT - as mentioned earlier, I don't think that's possible, as this function would have to be added post-submit and it doesn't seem we can edit this bit in SmartCapture. Why are you insisting on using SmartCapture, is it because of the Journey Builder functionality? This too can be added to a custom form.

Answer (score 2):

Although the documentation says it's possible to add [Smart Capture Form Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_smart_capture_form_actions.htm&type=5), I wasn't able to find that option anywhere.

**UPDATE:** Seems above is outdated, as it only works with Smart Capture in classic content view in Marketing Cloud Email Studio.

As a workaround, I'd suggest using Journey Builder.
When you create your SmartCapture form, check the box that says "Use in Journey Builder":

[image]

In Journey Builder, create a multi-step journey that creates a new Lead:

[image]

Inside the Lead activity, select "Create new" and fill in/map all the required fields:

[image]

Above will work if you really need to use SmartCapture, however, you would have much more flexibility if you create a custom form. As Lukas mentioned, here's a complete solution that you can just copy and paste: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/09/22/create-a-sales-service-cloud-integrated-lead-capture-form-using-ampscript/